# How to update the default line size of stat_smooth in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The newest ggplot2 version (2.0.0) changed the line size of stat smooth from 0.5 to 1. How could I update the default line size of `stat_smooth` into 0.5?

I tied this

```
update_stat_defaults("smooth", list(size = 0.5))
```

But it does not work.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: what is `update.stat.defaults`

Comment: I made a mistake. It is update_stat_defaults()

Comment: I find the same behaviour. I can change defaults for geoms with `update_geom_defaults()`, but the counterpart for stats does not seem to work. I have also tried `colour` and `linetype` and they all did not work.

Comment: you want to update the line, why are you using update stat? `update_geom_defaults("smooth", list(size = .5))` seems to give the expected result

Comment: but I agree (classic ggplot) that the help files are still pretty awful in 2.0

Comment: Thanks a lot, rawr. Your solution help me a lot.

Comment: It would be useful to post this as an answer and accept it. It is a good thing to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by rawr in comments (and not posted as an answer for a month now), the default line size of `stat_smooth` can be changed with:

`update_geom_defaults("smooth", list(size = .5))`

Other default sizes can be changed similarly.

Comment: Note that when updating the geom defaults for color, some only accept "colour" but not "color".  updating for "point" is one of these.